# Canned apricots; siphoning on several of the jars

Tags: canning

All of the jars have depressed buttons on the lids, and I can lift the jars by the lids.  I cannot forcibly remove the lids with my fingertips.  But when I use the spoon test several of them have a dullish sound. Also, even though I tried to remove air bubble, several of the jars have air bubbles.  Should I reprocess them or are they okay to store?

Comment: Can you clarify please: What is the spoon test? What do you mean by “siphoning”?

Comment: Hi.  Siphoning is when some of the product comes out of the jar during or just after processing.  It can leave food residue on the jar edge that can interfere with getting a good seal.  Tapping the top of the lid with the back of a spoon should give a higher pitched sound.  A dull sound indicates a potentially weaker seal.  I went ahead and replaced the lids and reprocessed them.  This has to be done within 24 hours of the original processing.  They all passed all tests after I reprocessed them so I can have a little more peace of mind that they are safe to store on the shelf.